# No response from Button and AlertDialog

Tags: java, php, android, database, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to connect my project app with an online database through cPanel Hosting. I used the AlertDialog.Builder, setOnClickListener, Try and Catch in Android Studio but it doesn't work. I'm using this for my login page. The login button won't redirect me to the Home activity. The alert dialog won't appear too.

Here is my Java file for the login page,

```
package daffaalmer.bloom2nd;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText EditTextEmail = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
    final EditText EditTextPassword = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.EditTextPassword);
    final Button ButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonLogin);
    final TextView TextViewRegister = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.TextViewRegister);

    TextViewRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            Login.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    ButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = EditTextEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = EditTextPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new 
Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = 
jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String email = jsonResponse.getString("email");

                            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Login.this, 
Home.class);
                            loginIntent.putExtra("name", name);
                            loginIntent.putExtra("email", email);
                            Login.this.startActivity(loginIntent);

                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email, password, 
            responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my XML file for the login page,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:paddingBottom="64dp"
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
android:paddingRight="50dp"
android:paddingTop="64dp"
tools:context="daffaalmer.bloom2nd.Login">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BloomLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_weight="0.26" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeWriting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/writing" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
        style="@style/edit_text_style"
        android:hint="E-mail Address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextPassword"
        style="@style/edit_text_style"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLogin"
        style="@style/button_style"
        android:text="LOG IN" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewRegister"
        style="@style/textView_style"
        android:text="Not a member yet? Sign Up"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java file for the LoginRequest,

```
package daffaalmer.bloom2nd;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = 
"daffaalmerf.5gbfree.com/Login.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> 
listener){
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null );
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("password", password);

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {return params;}

}
```

And here is my Login.php file in the database

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("daffaalmerf.5gbfree.com", "daffaalm_almer", 
"daffaalm2849", "daffaalm_pribadi_data");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM pribadi_data WHERE email = 
? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $dateofbirth, $address, 
$phonenumber, $email, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["dateofbirth"] = $dateofbirth;
    $response["address"] = $address;
    $response["phonenumber"] = $phonenumber;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: have you try to log the catch statement? maybe your code direct you there because it encounters some exceptions.

Comment: Log.i("your_tag", e.getMessage().toString()); The output is on the logcat

you can also use Toast if you want

Comment: Log.e("Login Failed", e.getMessage().toString()); It says that the e.getMessage().toString() is redundant

Comment: remove toString()

Comment: still got nothing. Is it because i use both "try and catch" and "if"?

Comment: how nothing? did you check the logcat?

Comment: Toast works. Log.d also works.  I have moved my AlertDialog to another part of the code and it displays just fine, it only doesn't work inside the onResponse(JSONObject response) method.  Still looking for answer.

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setTitle("Working here");
                        builder.setMessage("Check User Id & Password");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();